# Can I kern classes in luatex?

Tags: luatex, kerning

`fg` can be kerned thus

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua {
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "ktest",
        type = "kern",
        data = {
            ["f"] = { 
             ["g"] = 1000,
            }
        }
    }
}

\setmainfont{ebgaramond}[RawFeature=+ktest]

\begin{document}

abcdefghijklm.
a; b; c; d; f;

\end{document}
```

How about `<greekorlatinletter>;`?  Is it possible to kern classes?